# Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'firebase/firestore'

Tags: api, firebase

I am trying to run a very basic code on google api using firebase.

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
//const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
require("firebase/firestore");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
//var firestore = admin.firestore();
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

//firestore arguments defined
/* var addRef = firestore.collection('Admissions');
var feeRef = firestore.collection('Fees');
 */
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
  console.log("request.body.queryResult.parameters: ", request.body.queryResult.parameters);

  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
   var intentMap = new Map();


});
```

It gives me a error that says

> 'Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'firebase/firestore'.Try running "npm install" in your functions directory before deploying.

When I run npm install inside the funtions directory, I get:

> audited 9161 packages in 25.878s found 292 vulnerabilities (21 low,
>   207 moderate, 64 high)   run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm
>   audit` for details

Its been a week, I am stuck with these errors, these errors keep fluctuating based on the solution i find. But i am not able to overcome this error. Can you please check if there is something wrong I am doing, or anything else I need to try?

Comment: `firebase/firestore` is for client web apps.  `@google-cloud/firestore` is for server apps.

Comment: So what are you suggesting? What should I change in the code?

Comment: Yes, I'm suggesting you should use a different module for server side development with Cloud Firestore.

Comment: I am very new to this. Can you tell me how to use a different module and which module to use for this development?

Comment: There is lots of documentation.  https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.19.x/

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again. I was also stuck on this for a week. It is a corrupt file issue.